# Foreign-Domestic Symmetry

Tags: options, fx

I try to find the proof of the theorem of Foreign-Domestic Symmetry for FX options, but I did not found, Some paper or book, where it is explained?

Theorem 2.1 in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01387.pdf

Thx.

Comment: Is this paper by Mr. Wystup helpful to you? https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6671934.pdf

Comment: Thx, I read it, but there is no rigorous proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_t$ be the exchange rate from one unit foreign currency FGN to units of domestic currency DOM. Note that, for maturity $T$ and strike $K$,
\begin{align*}
\max(S_T-K, \, 0) = S_TK\max\Big(\frac{1}{K}-\frac{1}{S_T}, \, 0\Big).
\end{align*}

Moreover, let

- $B^d_t$ and $B^f_t$ be the respective domestic and foreign money-market account values at time $t$,
- $P^d$ and $P^f$ be the respective domestic and foreign risk-neutral measures,
- $E_d$ and $E_f$ be the respective expectations corresponding to $P^d$ and $P^f$.

Then, for $t\ge 0$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dP^d}{dP^f}\big|_t &= \frac{S_0 B^d_t}{S_t B^f_t}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
C_{DOM/FGN}(0, T, K) &= E_d\left(\frac{\max(S_T-K, \, 0)}{B^d_T} \right)\\
&=E_f\left(\frac{dP^d}{dP^f}\big|_T\frac{\max(S_T-K, \, 0)}{B^d_T} \right)\\
&=E_f\left(\frac{S_0 B^d_T}{S_T B^f_T}\,\frac{S_TK\max\big(\frac{1}{K}-\frac{1}{S_T}, 0\big)}{B^d_T} \right)\\
&=S_0 KE_f\left(\frac{\max\big(\frac{1}{K}-\frac{1}{S_T}, \, 0\big)}{B^f_T} \right)\\
&=S_0 K P_{FGN/DOM}\Big(0, T, \frac{1}{K}\Big).
\end{align*}